# Partitions of set with maximal cardinality

Tags: set-partition

Is there a way to compute the number of partitions such that each set in the partition has a cardinality lower or equal to two? If yes, is there also an efficient algorithm to compute these partitions?

Comment: Meaning the number of sets in the partition is at most $2$? Or the size of each set in the partition is at most $2$

Comment: It is the cardinality of each subset in the partition. I have adjusted the question.

Comment: This is tabulated, with lots of links, formulas, and references, at https://oeis.org/A000085

Comment: @GerryMyerson: That looks good! Do you also have some suggestion for an algorithm to compute such partitions?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson I just see your remark now...

Comment: Many formulas, and programs in various computer languages, are given at the OEIS site, Cesare.

Comment: You still there, Cesare? Jean Marie has given you an algorithm, right?

Comment: See my edit. May I have a reaction from you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us call "classes" the subsets of a given partition.

One can associate to any of these partitions in a unique way a **symmetric** boolean ((0-1) entries) matrix $P$ with $P_{i,j}=0$ everywhere excepted:

- $P_{i,i}=1$ if $\{i\}$ is a "class" with one-element (singleton),
- $P_{i,j}=P_{j,i}=1$ if $\{i,j\}$ is a "class" with two elements.

We can therefore reformulate the issue into counting the number of symmetric boolean matrices with sum of lines or columns equal to $1$, i.e., **symmetric permutation matrices**, i.e., as well
permutation matrices $P$ such that $P^2=I$.

This is known as the [OEIS A000085](http://oeis.org/A000085) with recurrence relationship:

$$a_n=a_{n-1}+(n-1)a_{n-2}$$

[A reference here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/288608/305862).

**Edit:** This approach provides a rather direct way to program all these partitions. Here is a Matlab program which does the job for any (reasonable) $n$ :

> ```
> n=5;
> T=perms(1:n), % the n! x n array of all permutations
> II=eye(n); % unit matrix
> p=0; % counts the number of solutions
> for k=1:factorial(n)
>     P=II(:,T(k,:)); % k-th permutation matrix
>     if P==P'
>         p=p+1;fprintf('%d: ',p);
>         D=diag(P);
>         E=find(D');
>         if any(E);fprintf('{%d}',E);end;
>         P=P-diag(D); % getting rid of diag. entries
>         [I,J]=find(P); % indices of nonzero entries
>         s=length(I);
>         if s>0
>         K=[I,J];U=find((J-I)>0);K=K(U,:);L=size(K,1);
>         for k=1:L;fprintf('{%d,%d}',K(k,:));end;
>         end;
>     fprintf('\n');
>     end;
> end;
> ```

Output for $n=5$:

```
 1: {3}{2,4}{1,5}
 2: {4}{2,3}{1,5}
 3: {2}{3}{4}{1,5}
 4: {2}{3,4}{1,5}
 5: {3}{1,4}{2,5}
 6: {5}{2,3}{1,4}
 7: {2}{3}{5}{1,4}
 8: {2}{1,4}{3,5}
 9: {5}{1,3}{2,4}
 10: {4}{1,3}{2,5}
 11: {2}{4}{5}{1,3}
 12: {2}{1,3}{4,5}
 13: {3}{1,2}{4,5}
 14: {3}{4}{5}{1,2}
 15: {4}{1,2}{3,5}
 16: {5}{1,2}{3,4}
 17: {1}{3}{5}{2,4}
 18: {1}{2,4}{3,5}
 19: {1}{4}{5}{2,3}
 20: {1}{2,3}{4,5}
 21: {1}{2}{3}{4}{5}
 22: {1}{2}{3}{4,5}
 23: {1}{2}{5}{3,4}
 24: {1}{2}{4}{3,5}
 25: {1}{3}{4}{2,5}
 26: {1}{3,4}{2,5}
```

Comment: Are you accustomed to Matlab ? If yes, a shorter program could be obtained using sparse matrices operators...